# Fast way to convert to Double a decimal formatted String without know what is this format

Tags: java, kotlin

I have this code in kotlin language:

```
val stringDecimalvalue = ... // can come as '#,###.##' or '#.###,##' and the two are valid
```

I want to create a `Double` with this `String` thus

```
var monetaryValue = Double(stringDecimalvalue)
```

If the value is in **#,###.##** format a `NumberFormatException` will be raised then I need know this pattern before to Format.

There is a way that I don't need scroll through the entire string or apply a regex with match ? (or maybe a light regex approach)

Thank you!

Comment: Just parse explicitly with both formats. You could write your own parser to make it a bit more efficient, but I can't imagine this to be the bottleneck in any application.

Comment: How do you want to parse the number if you don't know which character is the decimal point and which is the thousands separator? Is there a way of telling one from the other based on the format the number is in?

Comment: I expected that something like this work @Voo  `Double(DecimalFormat("0.#####").format("1,000.00"))` but returns a `IllegalArgumentException' saying that is not a valid number

Comment: If first get comma and then point I know that is in one, and reverse is true for the other, but I dont like it because I need to do others validation from here @DodgyCodeException

Comment: @ProfessorX Well certainly `"0.#####"` wouldn't match `"1,000.00"`- why would it? `#,###.##` on the other hand would. Simply catch the exception if it's not in `#,###.##` and then try `#.###,##`.

Comment: What about a number like `1.000`?  Is that a thousand, or the number 1 to three decimal places?  Unless you know in advance what format to expect, there will be some numbers you can't parse unambiguously.

Comment: @gidds You are ritght. No make sense my approach because we need know format before of perform in order to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to me seems to find the last appearance of `,` or `.` and remove all appearances of `.` and `.` before that, then you should be able to use `Double::parseString`

Answer (score 0):

In first place, I need to say that no make sense the approach of a general use propose function without a  explicit format because, like @gidds and @DodgyCodeException comments, it's subject to ambiguity.

Thus, I solve using a `regex` to match decimal point separator grouped by commas
 `[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*\\.[0-9]{2}` and the inverted case `[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]{2}` (comma separator grouped by points). Then clean commas and replace points in order to get the no grouped point decimal format that I want to parse to `Double`

I do this how a `extension function`:

```
const val NOTHING = ""
const val COMMA = ","
const val POINT = "."

val commaGrouped = "[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*\\.[0-9]{2}".toRegex()
val pointGrouped = "[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]{2}".toRegex()

fun String.commaCleaned() = replace(COMMA, NOTHING)

fun String.pointCleaned() = replace(POINT, NOTHING)

fun String.commaToPoint() = replace(COMMA, POINT)

fun String.pointToComma() = replace(POINT, COMMA)


fun String.toDouble() =
    when {
        commaGrouped matches this -> Double(commaCleaned())
        pointGrouped matches this -> Double(pointCleaned().commaToPoint())
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException(
            "the value ${this} can't be converted to ${Double::class.java} " +
                "have match ${commaGrouped.pattern} " +
                "or ${pointGrouped.pattern}")
    }
```

realize that a integer format or a more than two decimal precision will not match to create the `Double`, and is what I want too.